# Correct way to send multiple items to the paypal rest api in PHP

Tags: php, rest, paypal

What is the correct way to send multiple items to the paypal rest api? I have read through the docs and examples and as far as I can tell:

Declare Transaction

->Add Transaction Details

Declare New ItemList

Loop Orders

->Declare a new item for each order

->Add item details

End Loop

Add Items to ItemList

Add ItemList to Transaction

Add to transaction

This is the code I have been playing with to get this to work, however I get the usual paypal redirect error, which is the standard error when something is incorrect in the payment.

```
foreach ($orders as $unitcost)
{
    $totalamount = $totalamount + ($unitcost['price'] * $unitcost['quantity']);
}

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setamount($totalamount);
$transaction->setDescription('Order from Shop');
$itemList = new ItemList();

    foreach($orders as $unpaid)
        {

            $itemid = $unpaid['itemid'];
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM `items` WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $itemid);
            $stmt->execute();
            $name = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            $items = new Item();
            $items->setQuantity('1');
            $items->setName($name);
            $items->setPrice($unpaid['price']);
            $items->setCurrency($currency);





        }


$itemList->setItems(array($items)); 
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
```

I can succesfully send a single item using the amount and amountdetails classes, its just adding multiple items I am struggling with.

Comment: Ok, after a further bit of debugging, I can see that only the last item in the loop is being sent, this could explain the error as i see as the payments wont match up to the total amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

```
$i =0;
foreach($orders as $unpaid)

    {

        $itemid = $unpaid['itemid'];
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM `items` WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $itemid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $name = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $items[$i] = new Item();
        $items[$i]->setQuantity($unitcost['quantity'])->setName($name)->setPrice($unpaid['price'])->setCurrency($currency); 
        $i++;

    }

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems($items);    


$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
$transaction->setamount($amount)
```

;

Comment: thanks it helped me. Could not see the array() that was under my nose :)